# How to group a data.frame each integer number of rows?

Tags: r, aggregate

This seems to me a very simple question but I don't manage to come up with an efficient idea.

I have a data frame in R so composed:

- column `position` generated as `seq(from = 1, to = nrow(df), by = 1)`
- column `value`, with some values associated with the position

I want to group the dataframe each k rows (k being an integer input) and then calculate the mean of each group.

The dplyr function `group_by` does not allow me to group for a specific integer number of rows.

How can I do that? Is there a way to avoid creating the column position at all?

Comment: Try `df1 %>% group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), k, n()))) %>% summarise(value = mean(value))`

Comment: Absolutely perfect, consider updating as answer so can close the question!

Comment: Or `df1 %>% group_by(grp = (1:n() - 1) %/% k) %>% ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `gl` from `base R`.  Specify the `n` and `k` values.  The `n` would be the total number of rows in the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
k1 <- 5
df1 %>% 
  group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), k = k1, n()))) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value))
```